# what's wrong with my procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a procedure in mysql,but I can select nothing through the procedure,what's wrong with it?

```
delimiter //
create procedure getLineStasticFreightList(in start int(4),in row int(4),in stationIDD varchar(4),in dateStart datetime,in dateEnd datetime)
BEGIN
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS rqusg_lineStasticFreightUser;
CREATE VIEW rqusg_lineStasticFreightUser AS 
SELECT a.id, c.stationName as station,b.name as track,sum(a.dddwTime) AS zgdddwsj, sum(a.ddzxTime) AS zgddzxsj, sum(a.zxzyTime) AS zgzxzysj, sum(a.ddzngyTime) AS zgddzngysj, sum(a.hcddqsTime) AS zgddqssj
FROM rqusg_line_yard a
 join rqusg_line_tracks b
   on a.track = b.id
 join rqusg_line_stations c
   on a.stationID =  c.stationID
WHERE a.stationID = 'stationIDD' and a.arriveTime >= 'dateStart'  and a.clczTime <= 'dateEnd'
group by a.track
union
select a.id,c.stationName as station,b.name as track,sum(a.dddwTime) as zgdddwsj,sum(a.ddzxTime) as zgddzxsj,sum(a.zxzyTime) as zgzxzysj,sum(a.ddzngyTime) as zgddzngysj,sum(a.hcddqsTime) as zgddqssj
from rqusg_line_yard a
 join rqusg_line_tracks b
   on a.track = b.id
 join rqusg_line_stations c
   on a.stationID =  c.stationID
WHERE a.stationID = 'stationIDD' and a.arriveTime >= 'dateStart' and a.clczTime <= 'dateEnd'
group by a.track;
select * from rqusg_lineStasticFreightUser LIMIT start,row;
END
//
```

in my procedure,I create a view and select details from the view,but I can select nothing.I think there are something wrong in the params,but I am not sure.Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should not put quotes around the parameter variables:

```
WHERE a.stationID = stationIDD and a.arriveTime >= dateStart  and a.clczTime <= dateEnd
```

By the way, both subqueries in your UNION are identical. Why do you have the same query twice?

Answer (score 0):

You may get error at this line `WHERE a.stationID = 'stationIDD' and a.arriveTime >= 'dateStart'  and a.clczTime <= 'dateEnd'` because you are putting single quotes arround variable which converts it to constant string and not variable.So change it to

```
`WHERE a.stationID = stationIDD and a.arriveTime >= dateStart  and a.clczTime <=dateEnd`
```